# javascript 101: sales tax calculator does not respond to data entry

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm guessing the onload function is not properly implemented. Entering numbers or letters do not get the appropriate error or calculation response.

This is my code as of now:

http://jsfiddle.net/907yn57r/

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
var calculateTaxAndTotals = function () {
    var taxRate = parseFloat($("taxRate").value); //The tax rate, as a percentage (e.g. 8.5)
    var subTotal = parseFloat($("itemPrice").value); //An item price ex $5.95

    $("salesTax").value = "";
    $("totalItemCost").value = "";

    if (isNaN(taxRate) || taxRate <= 0) {
        document.taxCalc.taxRate.focus();
        document.$("taxRateMessage").firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a valid value.";
    } else if (isNaN(itemPrice) || itemPrice <= 0) {
        document.$("priceMessage").firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a valid value.";
    } else {
        var salesTax = subTotal * (taxRate / 100);
        var totalItemCost = salesTax + itemPrice;
        $("orderTotal").focus();
        alert(totalItemCost);
    }

}

window.onload = function () {
    calculateTaxAndTotals();
}
```

Comment: You need to add some code to link to jsfiddles. Additionally, this lets us know what portions of the code are problematic

Comment: Where did you get this code from? It looks like it's from some tutorial...

Comment: Pretty much, I m working thru a Murach's book.

Comment: I may have changed the jsfiddle while both of you were editing it. Im not touching it now.

Comment: You don't need to change anything else except what I changed my in my answer (i.e. the javascript). Check out the fiddle I linked to to see it in action. If you want, you can add an event handler to autocalculate after entry, but that's outside the scope of the question.

Comment: I still keep on getting the error message for the item price field.

Comment: You're getting an error when running my fiddle? (and if you want me to be notified about your comment, write @General_Twyckenham in your comment)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems.

First of all, JSFiddle deals with the main html structure itself, so you don't need new `body` tags and the like.

Secondly, the Javascript here needs to be loaded in the head or the body (on the top left in JSFiddle you can choose different places for it to be loaded).

Finally, there's a few errors in the definition for `CalculateTaxAndTotals`, it should say

```
if (isNaN(taxRate) || taxRate <= 0) {
        document.taxCalc.taxRate.focus();
        $("taxRateMessage").firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a valid value.";
    } else if (isNaN(subTotal) || itemPrice <= 0) {
        $("priceMessage").firstChild.nodeValue = "Please enter a valid value.";
    } else {
        var salesTax = subTotal * (taxRate / 100);
        var totalItemCost = salesTax + itemPrice;
        $("orderTotal").focus();
        alert(totalItemCost);
    }
```

[Really Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/907yn57r/15/)

The final issue was that you were calling `isNaN` on `itemPrice`, but the variable `itemPrice` didn't exist.